# How to define a custom loss function in Flux.jl?

Tags: julia, flux.jl

Looking at the Flux.jl docs, I see there a ton of built in loss functions: https://fluxml.ai/Flux.jl/stable/models/losses/. My question is how can I define and use my own loss function in Flux if I want something more esoteric?

Comment: Check out the [sources](https://github.com/FluxML/Flux.jl/blob/0a215462ad8e0ba795205c9e94864403207d63fa/src/losses/functions.jl#L6-L20) -- they are really just regular functions.

Comment: So the only requirement is that they return a numerical (float) value?

Comment: I suppose anything the AD is happy with goes (c.f. [here](https://fluxml.ai/Flux.jl/stable/models/basics/#Building-Simple-Model)). My understanding is that the provided losses are only a convenience collection of stable implementation of common functions. But then, I've never used Flux (that's why I don't make an answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any differentiable function which returns a single float value as your loss, as stated in the comment above, the prepared functions are just for your convenience.
You can pass anything e.g.

```
using Flux
yourcustomloss(ŷ, y) = sum(.- sum(y .* logsoftmax(ŷ), dims = 1))
```

and calculate the gradient of it or pass it to `train!` function.